# area enclosed within 3 lines

Tags: geometry, area

Equations of lines $L1$ and $L2$ are $y = x − 2$ and $y = −2x − 2$. 
If $y = −x$ is the angle bisector of lines $L2$ and $L3$, 
then what is the area enclosed within the 3 lines $L1, L2$ and $L3$?

equation of line $L1$ is ==> 
$y = x-2$
Equation of line $L2$ is ==>
$y = -2x-2$

> !can I find the coordinates of intersection of three line, if yes how?
>   If there intersection points are found then we can find length of sides and then apply hero's formula
>   i.e Area $= \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$

Comment: One way: find points of intersection, find distances between points, find all angles, use one angle to get a height, use area formula.

Comment: One point of intersection: x-2 = -2x-2 so x=0 and y=-2.

Comment: Can you find $L3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is artificially constructed in such a way that all calculated data are integers (or the square root of an integer). Referring to the diagram below:-
[image]

A. By solving L(1) and L(2), $A = (0, –2)$.

B. $L(1)$ cuts the x-axis at $B = (2, 0)$.

C. $L$ cuts $L(1)$ at $C = (1, –1)$.

D. By considering the slopes of $L(1)$ and $L$, $L \perp L(1)$.

E. $L(2)$ and $L$ intersect at $D = (-2, 2)$.

F. BY [$ASA$], $\triangle DAC$ must congruent to $\triangle DXC$ for some point $X$ on $AC$ produced.

G. $X$ happens to be $B$ because $\triangle OAB$, $\triangle OAC$ and $\triangle OCB$ are all $45^\circ-45^\circ-90^\circ$ right angled triangles.

The above provides all the necessary information to compute the required area.